# Will it cause error if I launch MediaRecorder.start() in suspend fun and launch MediaRecorder.stop() in normal fun in Android?

Tags: android, android-service, kotlin-coroutines

Recording audio is a long time operation, so I launch `mRecorder?.start()` in a coroutine within a service, you can see RecordService.kt.

I invoke `suspend fun startRecord(){...}` in `AndroidViewModel` with `viewModelScope.launch { }` to start record audio.

I only invoke a normal `fun stopRecord(){...}` in `AndroidViewModel` to stop record audio, you can see HomeViewModel.kt,  will it cause error with the object `var mRecorder: MediaRecorder?` ?

**HomeViewModel.kt**

```
class HomeViewModel(val mApplication: Application, private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository) : AndroidViewModel(mApplication) {

    private var mService: RecordService? = null

    private val serviceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
        override fun onServiceConnected(className: ComponentName, iBinder: IBinder) {
            val binder = iBinder as RecordService.MyBinder
            mService = binder.service
        }
       ...
    }


    fun bindService() {
        Intent(mApplication , RecordService::class.java).also { intent ->
            mApplication.bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
        }
    }  

    fun unbindService() {
        Intent(mApplication, RecordService::class.java).also { intent ->
            mApplication.unbindService(serviceConnection)
        }
    }

    fun startRecord(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            mService?.startRecord()
        }
    }

    fun stopRecord(){
        mService?.stopRecord()
    }      
}
```

**RecordService.kt**

```
class RecordService : Service() {

    private var mRecorder: MediaRecorder? = null

    suspend fun startRecord(){

        mRecorder = MediaRecorder()

        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            mRecorder?.setOutputFile(filename);

            mRecorder?.setMaxDuration(1000*60*20); //20 Mins
            mRecorder?.setAudioChannels(1);
            mRecorder?.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
            mRecorder?.setAudioEncodingBitRate(192000);

            mRecorder?.prepare()
            mRecorder?.start()
        }
    }


    fun stopRecord(){
        mRecorder?.stop()
        mRecorder=null
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think it will cause any error.

Comment: Why you are putting it in a coroutine when your entire code is run on a Service?

Comment: Thanks! You know that Service is running in main thread, it will block UI if Idon't run `mRecorder?.start()` in another thread, and a coroutine can make `mRecorder?.start()`  running in another thread.

Comment: This code does have a race condition.

I'm guessing that `withContext` will trigger a memory barrier, but if not, then `mRecorder` is not getting safely published to the IO thread.

Other problem is the nulling from `stopRecord` may not be visible to the IO thread, so if `stopRecord` is called while the IO thread is initializing, then `mRecorder?.stop()` will be called before `mRecorder?.stop()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't cause error but if you face runtime error while calling this method it may be caused by the recorder didn't receive any valid sound or video to record. Check below documentation link for more information.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#stop()